# JavaScript - Move JSON Array Up or Down

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "David",
        "value": 1000
    },
    {
        "name": "Damian",
        "value": 100
    }
]
```

I want to check it and sort it, so the end result will be this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "David",
        "value": 1000
    },
    {
        "name": "Damian",
        "value": 100
    }
    {
        "name": "John",
        "value": 10
    },
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What does "check it" mean? On which property do you want to sort? Have you done any research into solving this yourself? Have you made any attempts to solve this yourself?

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "David",
        "value": 1000
    },
    {
        "name": "Damian",
        "value": 100
    }
]

const result = data.sort((a, b) => a.value < b.value);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: 1º: your solution logs a different value than the one that OP wants. 2º: Question already have many duplicated ones in Stackoverflow, so it can be flagged as duplicated and don't need answer, OP just need to research a little bit

Comment: How does it log a different solution? It orders the array of objects by value descending. 
I didn't see that it was marked as duplicate until after I already posted it.

Comment: 10, 1000, 100 are not ordered.

Comment: You have to hit "run code snippet" to see the execution of my code...

Comment: as stated, it is not ordered, it displays: 10, 1000, 100... yes, in the console.log after hit run

Comment: Calvin, the data inside 'result' is now ordered. I simply log it so you can see the data. I don't know how to be any clearer.

Comment: Me also, because your array **is not** ordered, you are logging `result` (the log shows those values: 10, 1000, 100) this **is not** ordered as expected (that is 1000, 100, 10)...  You can see it in the console.log... but anyway, the answer is yours, you do what you want with it

Comment: Well my issue was that sort returns a value not a boolean. You should be using `-` not `<`

Comment: Buddy, result is a sorted array sorted by the 'value' property in descending order.